# Apply numpy.searchsorted method to an array loaded from textfile using numpy.loadtxt

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, large-data

I am currently working on a bioinformatics project and I need to solve the following problem.

I have a textfile "chr1.txt" containing two columns: positions on a chromosome and boolean variable True or False.

0 false
10000 true
10001 true
10005 false
10007 true
10011 false
10013 true
10017 false
10019 false
10023 false
10025 true
10029 true
10031 false
10035 true
10037 false
....
This data means that regions from 0 to 10000 are repetitive or (=unmappable --> false), from 10000 to 10005 are unique (=mappable --> true), from 10005 to 10007 are again repetitive and so on. The file ends at a position 248'946'406 and has 15'948'271 lines. To find a general solution to the problem I would like to restrict the file to the lines you can see above.

I want to load this textfile to a numpy array consisting of two columns. For that I used numpy.loadtxt:

```
import numpy as np    
with open('chr1.txt','r') as f:
        chr1 = np.loadtxt(f, dtype={'names':('start','mappable'),
        'formats':('i4','S1')})
```

Here is the output:

```
In [39]: chr1
Out[39]: 
array([(0, b'f'), (10000, b't'), (10001, b't'), (10005, b'f'),
       (10007, b't'), (10011, b'f'), (10013, b't'), (10017, b'f'),
       (10019, b'f'), (10023, b'f'), (10025, b't'), (10029, b't'),
       (10031, b'f'), (10035, b't'), (10037, b'f')], 
      dtype=[('position start', '<i4'), ('mappable', 'S1')])
```

This doesn't look perfect to me since I want the second column to be recognised as boolean type, but I didn't find a way to do so.

As next I want to throw a random number in between positions 10000 and 10037.

```
In [49]: np.random.randint(10000,10037)
Out[49]: 10012
```

Now I want to apply the numpy.searchsorted method to the first column of my array to find out whether my genome is uniquely mappable at that position. So what I want as an output in this case is 5 (index of the element (10011, b'f') in my array). If I am trying to extract an array consisting of only the first column - positions, I get an error:

```
In [21]: chr1[:,0]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-a63d052f1c5d> in <module>()
----> 1 chr1[:,0]

IndexError: too many indices for array
```

I guess this is because my array doesn't really have two columns

```
In [40]: chr1.shape
Out[40]: (15,)
```

So how can I extract only the positions and apply searchsorted method on them using my existing array? Should I load my textfile to an array in a different way so that there are really two columns, first being of an integer type and the second - boolean?

```
extracted_array=[0,10000,10001,10005,10007,10011,10013,10017,10019,10023,10025,10029,10031,10035,10037]
np.searchsorted(extracted_array,10012)-1
Out[58]: 5
```

Then I would look with a found index whether second argument is true or false and be able to make a conclusion if the position is within a mappable region.

Would really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can extract the data corresponding to `position start` with `chr1['position start']` and similarly for the second field. We will get the boolean array of valid ones with a comparison against `'t'`.

Thus, we would have one approach, like so -

```
indx = chr1['position start']
mask = chr1['mappable']=='t'
rand_num = np.random.randint(10000,10037)
matched_indx = np.searchsorted(indx, rand_num)-1

if mask[matched_indx]:
    print "It is mappable!"
else:
    print "It is NOT mappable!"
```

1) Getting the data and mask/boolean array -

```
In [283]: chr1   # Input array
Out[283]: 
array([(    0, 'f'), (10000, 't'), (10001, 't'), (10005, 'f'),
       (10007, 't'), (10011, 'f'), (10013, 't'), (10017, 'f'),
       (10019, 'f'), (10023, 'f'), (10025, 't'), (10029, 't'),
       (10031, 'f'), (10035, 't'), (10037, 'f')], 
      dtype=[('position start', '<i4'), ('mappable', 'S1')])

In [284]: indx = chr1['position start']
     ...: mask = chr1['mappable']=='t'
     ...: 

In [285]: indx
Out[285]: 
array([    0, 10000, 10001, 10005, 10007, 10011, 10013, 10017, 10019,
       10023, 10025, 10029, 10031, 10035, 10037], dtype=int32)

In [286]: mask
Out[286]: 
array([False,  True,  True, False,  True, False,  True, False, False,
       False,  True,  True, False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

2) Get a random number and use `searchsorted` and use IF-ELSE part -

```
In [297]: rand_num = 10012 # np.random.randint(10000,10037)

In [298]: matched_indx = np.searchsorted(indx, rand_num)-1

In [299]: matched_indx
Out[299]: 5

In [300]: if mask[matched_indx]:
     ...:     print "It is mappable!"
     ...: else:
     ...:     print "It is NOT mappable!"
     ...:     
It is NOT mappable!
```

Comment: Thank you! This is awsome:) I will test it on my large files too and come back again to accept the answer!